# How to group consecutive numbers using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I've the following problem which I think it has a simple solution, I just don't have the knowledge.

I've this input for example:

```
<set>
  <value>8</value>
  <value>1</value>
  <value>2</value>
  <value>10</value>
  <value>4</value>
  <value>22</value>
  <value>12</value>
  <value>45</value>
  <value>11</value>
  <value>3</value>
  <value>5</value>
  <value>9</value>
  <value>21</value>
  <value>6</value>
  <value>7</value>
  <value>13</value>
</set>
```

I want to create sequences with max 10 elements each where the numbers are consecutive and in ascending order.

Desired output:

```
<MOrd>
  <range>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>8</value>
    <value>9</value>
    <value>10</value>
  </range>
  <range>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
    <value>13</value>
  </range> 
  <range>
    <value>21</value>
    <value>22</value>
  </range>
  <range>
    <value>45</value>
  </range>
</Mord>
```

I've this code so far but have no idea how to proceed:

```
<MOrd>
  <xsl:for-each select="$Set">
    <xsl:sort select="value" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="value" group-by"value">
      <range>
        <xsl:if test=".">
          <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </value>
        </xsl:if>
      </range>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:for-each>
</MOrd>
```

How would you go from here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to group the elements by a simple mathematical expression to determine how many times 10 divides into the number

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="value" group-by="floor((number(.) - 1) div 10)">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="set">
    <MOrd>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="value" group-by="floor((number(.) - 1) div 10)">
          <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
          <range>
               <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                     <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="." />
               </xsl:for-each>
           </range>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
    </MOrd>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following is output

```
<MOrd>
   <range>
      <value>1</value>
      <value>2</value>
      <value>3</value>
      <value>4</value>
      <value>5</value>
      <value>6</value>
      <value>7</value>
      <value>8</value>
      <value>9</value>
      <value>10</value>
   </range>
   <range>
      <value>11</value>
      <value>12</value>
      <value>13</value>
   </range>
   <range>
      <value>21</value>
      <value>22</value>
   </range>
   <range>
      <value>45</value>
   </range>
</MOrd>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but that doesn't work for me: see bellow my problem again

Comment: I've made a small tweak to my answer with regards the "number()" function. You can add a '.' to it, if your processor is demanding an argument, to represent the current node.

Comment: That's ok to group max 10 elements and if numbers are in the same decimal.. does not work for what I want like this case:
g[1]= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
g[2] = 8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12

Comment: Hmmm... Now I see what you mean. That's going to be quite trickier, and I currently don't know what the best solution is.

Comment: group-by="number(.)-position()" solves that problem..
Is it possible to put the other condition as well? I've tried like this: number(.)-position() and floor (position() div 11) but with no success.

Comment: number(.)-position() + floor(position() div 10)
almost almost almost, oh and I'm leaving aside the sorting function..
Yeah, It's tricky

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it seems like the issue at hand, grouping consecutive numbers, was not (fully) answered. You can do that using `group-starting-with` in XSLT 2.0 as follows (after you sorted the input):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="value" 
    group-starting-with="value[xs:integer(preceding-sibling::value[1]) + 1 != xs:integer(.)]">
    <range>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </range>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

The approach works because it triggers a new group each time the previous sibling is not one lower than the current node. If your input is `1,2,3,6,7,8,12,16,17` it will be grouped as `1,2,3`, `6,7,8`, `12` and `16,17`.

The solution works with XSLT 2.0 and 3.0, but not with XSLT 1.0.