# Group consecutive numbers in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

How to handle the below type of scenario using XSLT?

**Example 1:**

**Input:** `<cross-refs>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]</cross-refs>`

**Excepted output:** `<cross-refs>[5-9]</cross-refs>`

**Example 2:**

**Input:** `<cross-refs>[4, 6, 7, 8, 9]</cross-refs>`

**Excepted output:** `<cross-refs>[4,6-9]</cross-refs>`

**Example 3:**

**Input:** `<cross-refs>[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12,13]</cross-refs>`

**Excepted output:** `<cross-refs>[4-7,9,11-13]</cross-refs>`

**Example 4:**

**Input:** `<cross-refs>[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]</cross-refs>`

**Excepted output:** `<cross-refs>[4-7,9-13]</cross-refs>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: A single example is not sufficient to establish a rule. For example, what is the expected result for  input [4, 5, 6, 8, 9]?  Or [4, 6, 8, 9]? Or ...??

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for your response. I've added more cases.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495207/how-to-group-consecutive-numbers-using-xslt/30288840#30288840

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>
  <cross-refs>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]</cross-refs>
  <cross-refs>[4, 6, 7, 8, 9]</cross-refs>
  <cross-refs>[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13]</cross-refs>
  <cross-refs>[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]</cross-refs>
</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="cross-refs">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(translate(., '[]', ''), ', ')" />
                <xsl:for-each-group select="$tokens" group-adjacent="number(.) - position()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) > 1">
                        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]" />
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>           
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <cross-refs>5-9</cross-refs>
   <cross-refs>4,6-9</cross-refs>
   <cross-refs>4-7,9,11-13</cross-refs>
   <cross-refs>4-7,9-13</cross-refs>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks, it has worked on most of the cases. However, we encountered a failure case. In continuous three numbers, use a hyphen if required. 

Input: <cross-refs>[5, 6, 8, 9]</cross-refs>
Excepted Output: <cross-refs>[5, 6, 8, 9]</cross-refs>
Current Output: <cross-refs>[5-6, 8-9]</cross-refs>

Comment: @MaheshM Now you understand why examples can only illustrate a rule, not replace it. Anyway, you see how it's done, so you can make your own adjustments.